# there are no features in cv2 python always

Tags: python, image, opencv

I want to make app to match two images and find where is the target that I'm tracking, in fastest way, without lose tracking.

I used ORG but some times the features don't work (there are no features), and I used machine learning but it was really so slow.

Comment: If you already wrote code, _especially_ if you wrote code twice, remember that this is [not a general help forum](/help/on-topic) and you should put [all the details, including code you tried](/help/how-to-ask), in your post.

Answer (score 0):

There are several feature matching algorithms when it comes to feature matching. ORB (Oriented FAST and Rotated BRIEF) algorithm is experimentally two orders of magnitude faster than SIFT feature matching algorithm. For comparing the features of 2 images, you can use it as below,

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

    
# Read the query image as query_img
# and train image This query image
# is what you need to find in train image
# Save it in the same directory
# with the name image.jpg
query_img = cv2.imread('query.jpg')
train_img = cv2.imread('train.jpg')

# Convert it to grayscale
query_img_bw = cv2.cvtColor(query_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
train_img_bw = cv2.cvtColor(train_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Initialize the ORB detector algorithm
orb = cv2.ORB_create()

# Now detect the keypoints and compute
# the descriptors for the query image
# and train image
queryKeypoints, queryDescriptors = orb.detectAndCompute(query_img_bw,None)
trainKeypoints, trainDescriptors = orb.detectAndCompute(train_img_bw,None)

# Initialize the Matcher for matching
# the keypoints and then match the
# keypoints
matcher = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = matcher.match(queryDescriptors,trainDescriptors)

# draw the matches to the final image
# containing both the images the drawMatches()
# function takes both images and keypoints
# and outputs the matched query image with
# its train image
final_img = cv2.drawMatches(query_img, queryKeypoints,
train_img, trainKeypoints, matches[:20],None)

final_img = cv2.resize(final_img, (1000,650))

# Show the final image
cv2.imshow("Matches", final_img)
cv2.waitKey(3000)
```